# Android Play sounds in a sequence

Tags: android

I am currently trying to create an android app that plays a different sequence of sounds based on user input. Is there a simple way to play a sequence of sounds I have looked at mediaplayer and soundpool but it does not look like they where designed for sequential.

Thank you RandyFreak that is probably the better way. But I actually Ended up doing it a little differently.

I created a list of fileDescriptors pointing to sounds and added an oncomplete listener to mediaplayer. And every time the media player completed it's current sound it would play the first sound in the list and remove it from the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this issue a few months ago.

How I overcame this was I created a different mediaplayer for each sound and played them in the order that I needed.

That would be the simplest method.

I hope this helps

RF